# Continue sentence after enumeration — comma needed/advised?

Tags: commas, lists

I have a sentence that continues after an enumeration, such as the following:

```
Due to X, it is difficult for researchers, lecturers and students, 
but also expert engineers, to apply Y.
```

I'm wondering whether or not the comma after `engineers` is needed. My gut feeling says yes, for the reason that it separates the enumeration from the continuing sentence.

Unfortunately, I can't find any source that discusses this situation. Does anybody here know a source, or has good arguments for/against the comma?

Comment: I think the reason why you're opting for the unacceptable  'but' here is to indicate a _rather startling_ additional member to the list. Andrew's second suggestion provides the [not quite] 'shock, horror' subtext, but so would 'Due to X, it is difficult for researchers, lecturers and students – _and  also expert engineers_ –  to apply Y'. For even more horror, an italicised exclamation mark could be added to the parenthetical, before the closing dash.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Well put! That is indeed why *but* was used. I'll probably go with Andrew's second suggestion; for me, yours seems to cause slightly too much "shock" than I'd like to. But the dashes are definitely worth keeping in mind, thank you.

Comment: I'd use ' ... and even ...'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary, but not because it separates an enumerated list, rather it marks off a parenthetical insertion. The phrase "but also expert engineers" is inserted and needs to be set off with commas (or dashes):

> Due to X, it is difficult for researchers, lecturers and students to apply Y.
>
> Due to X, it is difficult for researchers, lecturers and students, 
>   but also expert engineers, to apply Y.

Note that because "it is difficult" is a positive statement [albeit stating an undesirable situation], you can't use the negative *but*. You need *and.*

You can use *but* if the overall sentence is negative, say with *not only:*

> Due to X, it is difficult for researchers, lecturers and students, 
>   and also expert engineers, to apply Y.
>
> Due to X, it is difficult not only for researchers, lecturers and students, 
>   but also expert engineers, to apply Y.

Comment: So ... +1 for my gut feeling, -1 for my technical understanding ;-) Just to clarify: are all four example sentences of yours grammatically correct? "you can't use the negative 'but'" suggests to me that the second sentence is actually wrong.

Comment: You're right, it's wrong: the first set of examples are your sentence (to show parenthesis); the second set demonstrates negative polarity.